# False routing in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, async.js

I am trying to use the following filter to divert packages but it fails:
I've build to routes using express.js:

```
app.get('/billdetails/:year/:month/:phoneId', function (req, res, next) {
    var db = req.db;
    var year = req.params.year;
    var month = req.params.month;
    var phoneId = req.params.phoneId;
    async.parallel({...})

app.get('/billdetails/lastinvoices/:number/:limit', function (req, res, next) {
    var db = req.db;
    var number = req.params.number;
    var limit = req.params.limit;
    async.parallel({...})
```

So when i request the first URL everything works fine, but when I try to request the second route I get the same response as from the first one.

Does anybody know why this happens?

Regards and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first route takes the same amount of parameters as the second.
That means that when you request the second route it will test the first one first, cause its defined before.

That means that if you request route two with the following request:
`url/billdetails/lastinvoices/12/123`

You will get routed to the first route with the following parameters:

```
year:    "lastinvoices"
month:   12
phoneId: 123
```

You could possibly define the second route before and by that let it try that first. But I'm not 100% sure that it would be safe to bet that it will always work.

Personally I would rename the route or rather fetch the limit parameter from a normal get-param, i.e: `url/billdetails/lastinvoices/1?limit=1` instead. 
So the second route would be defined as:
`/billdetails/lastinvoices/:number`